# Angular 9 animate a stepper component

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am trying to create a component that can (potentially) have as many children as needed.
So I created a stepper component which consists of two components, the parent (Stepper) and child (Step).
They are pretty simple in design, the stepper html looks like this:

```
<div class="panes">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

And the step html looks like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'expanded': expanded}"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

In my application it is a little more advanced, but you will get the idea if I keep it simple :)
I have created a stackblitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsj2na

Now I have the stepper, I would like to create some animations.
There are a couple of ways I could do this, but I started with this idea:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkgh4v

This works in a crude way, but it doesn't take into consideration n+ steps.
I would love to use Angular Animations, but I have no idea how to pass variables to it (or even if you can!)
I had this animation declared:

```
trigger('slide', [
  state('left', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
  state('right', style({ transform: 'translateX(-50%)' })),
  transition('* => *', animate(300)),
]),
```

But as you can see, this only works with 2 steps....
Can anyone help?

Comment: what do you want me to do when it comes to the last step? to get it from the beginning?

Comment: to work like this example https://eljallo.herokuapp.com/, is made in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this to a reasonable state.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4psjsm

As you can see, I have managed to use `[style.transform]` and `[style.width.%]` and although it works (and doesn't care how many steps there are) it doesn't use angular animation. I did some reading last night and can see how to pass variables to animations:

https://medium.com/@danieltamirr/parameterized-angular-animations-fa73a2727158

But the problem I have is how to stipulate the actual animation. If someone could help with that, then I will mark theirs as the answer